# Free elements from Wait -Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm struggling with Anylogic.
I would like every outgoing agent from an element (SelectOutput (on exit=true)) to invoke an agent waiting in a wait block.
So in the SelectOutput I wrote:

```
if (wait.size()>0 && agent.parameter=="xx") {
       wait.free(wait.get(0)); 
}
```

The problem is that in this way I am having 10 items that pass through the Selectoutput, but 5 are freed.
If I traceline the element (wait.get(0)) I get the same agent twice (e.g. agent[0] agent[0])), but only one is freed effectively.

I think the problem is `wait.get(0)`, but how can I solve the problem?
I need to free the exact number of agents as the ones passing in the selectOutput.

Comment: Is "xx" a String? If so you should rather use .equals("xx") also be very careful with select outputs  - the code is not always executed when you think it is... you can add a delay or use other functionality - check here for more https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/select-output-misbehaving

Comment: Which part helped you so that I can add it as an answer ;-) and you can approve it